# Dynamically adding options to drop down box

Tags: javascript

I have a drop down box in which values are entered dynamically. But sometimes it's value does not get refreshed. How can I force the drop down box to refresh?

```
var DropdownBox =document.getElementById("xyz");
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text="txt";
optn.value="val";
DropdownBox.options.add(optn);
```

Answer (score 1):

That should be `DropdownBox.add(optn);`, I believe.  See the [MDC page describing HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLSelectElement#add).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
DropdownBox.appendChild(optn);
```

?

Afaik `options.add()` is only supported in IE.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
var target=document.getElementById('myselect');    
var optionName = new Option('option text', 'option value');    
var targetlength = target.length;    
target.options[targetlength] = optionName;
```